# Run the constructor function in extended class

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm playing with `extends` in Node.js. I created a class named `Person` and another class which extends the `Person` one, called `Worker`. The `Worker` class has a `work` function which works perfectly (it shows the `getName()` result, defined in `Person`). I want to add another parameter for the `Worker` constructor.

I tried that by adding the `constructor` function in the `Worker`, like below:

```
"use strict";

class Person {
    constructor (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Worker extends Person {
    // Without this constructor, everything works correctly
    // But I want to add the type field
    constructor (name, type) {
        console.log(1);
        // this.type = type;
    }
    work () {
        console.log(this.getName() + " is working.");
    }
}

var w = new Worker("Johnny", "builder");
w.work();
```

When running this I get the following error:

```
path/to/my/index.js:14
        console.log(1);
                ^

ReferenceError: this is not defined
    at Worker (/path/to/my/index.js:14:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/index.js:22:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Why is this appearing? Also, how can I correctly do this?

I want to have the `type` field accessible in the `w` instance:

```
console.log(w.type);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `super()` in your extended constructor. Without that, it's not calling the constructor in your `Person` class.

```
class Person {
    constructor (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Worker extends Person {
    constructor (name, type) {
        super(name);
        this.type = type;
    }
    work () {
        console.log(this.getName() + " is working.");
    }
}
```

The following should now work:

```
var w = new Worker("Johnny", "builder");
w.work();
console.log(w.type); //builder
```